# Why does the `bool` data type render my data structure unreadable to avr-gdb?

Tags: gcc, gdb, avr

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
.
.
.
typedef struct Input {
    uint8_t pin;        /**< Pin associated with this input */
    bool state,         /**< Current pin state */
         last_state;    /**< Pin state last time we checked */
} Input;
```

I initialize the data structure like this:

```
Input *input = (Input *)malloc(sizeof(Input));
input->pin = 0;
input->state = false;
input->last_state = false;
```

I am compiling the code with `avr-gcc` 7.2.0 and running the code using [simulavr](https://www.nongnu.org/simulavr/) ("SimularAVR 1.2dev") and attaching to it using `avr-gdb`.

When I print out the data structure in `gdb` just after initialization I see this:

```
(gdb) p *input
$1 = {pin = 0 '\000', state = false}
```

Note that the `last_state` member isn't showing up.  Futhermore, if I set either one of the existing members, it appears that they are actually referring to the same location:

```
(gdb) set input->pin=123
(gdb) p *input
$8 = {pin = 123 '{', state = 123}
```

If I change the data type of `state` and `last_state` from `bool` to, say, `uint8_t`, like this...

```
typedef struct Input {
    uint8_t pin;        /**< Pin associated with this input */
    uint8_t state,      /**< Current pin state */
            last_state; /**< Pin state last time we checked */
} Input;
```

...then everything displays correctly:

```
(gdb) p *input
$1 = {pin = 0 '\000', state = 0 '\000', last_state = 0 '\000'}
```

What's going on here? Is this a bug in `gdb`? In `simulavr`? Something else? Note that the code itself runs correctly when deployed on the target microcontroller (an attiny85); this is entirely a debugging/simulation issue.

Comment: Hey, -1 voter, I would love some feedback about what in this question offended you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a bug in gdb?

It is definitely a bug in either `gdb` or `avr-gcc` -- either the debug info is incorrect (bug in `gcc`) or GDB is not interpreting it correctly (bug in GDB).

The `simulavr` has nothing to do with this.

To find out more, `readelf -wi a.out` and compare the description of `struct Input` in the working and non-working case. They should only differ in the type of `state` and `last_state` fields. If that's what you in fact observe, GDB bug is most likely.